# why does xpath remove html special characters?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

why does this

```
$html = '<a href="/browse/product.do?cid=1&amp;vid=1&amp;pid=1" class="productItemName">what is going on here</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadhtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$selectors['link'] = '//a/@href';
$links_nodeList = $xpath->query($selectors['link']);

foreach ($links_nodeList as $link) {
    $links[] = $link->nodeValue;
}

echo("<p>links</p>");
echo("<pre>");
print_r($links);
echo("</pre>");
```

output

```
links

Array
(
    [0] => /browse/product.do?cid=1&vid=1&pid=1
)
```

and not

```
links

Array
(
    [0] => /browse/product.do?cid=1&amp;vid=1&amp;pid=1
)
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The answer is simple**:

`&amp;` is a special way to represent the character `"&"` in an XML document.

**These two denote the same character**.

When the escaped form of the ampersand is output as text (not as XML), showing it as `"&"` is correct.

**As further elaborated by @LarsH in his comment**:

> when you say `loadhtml($html)`;, you are parsing the string as HTML,
>   which means that character entities (like `&amp;`) are interpreted
>   into the characters they represent (like `&`). If you want a string
>   that will be interpreted as `&amp;`, you need to escape the ampersand,
>   e.g. `&amp;amp;`

Comment: +1 good answer. To elaborate: when you say `loadhtml($html);`, you are parsing the string as HTML, which means that character entities (like `&amp;`) are interpreted into the characters they represent (like `&`). If you want a string that will be interpreted as `&amp;`, you need to escape the ampersand, e.g. `&amp;amp;`.

Comment: @LarsH: Good additional explanation.