# PHP. XPath. Call to str_replace() cause an 'unterminated entity' error.

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

Using XPath to parse this link

```
$html = '<a href="/browse/product.do?cid=1&amp;vid=1&amp;pid=1" class="productItemName">what is going on here</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadhtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$selectors['link'] = '//a/@href';
$links_nodeList = $xpath->query($selectors['link']);

foreach ($links_nodeList as $link) {
    $link->nodeValue = str_replace("http://www.test.com",'',$link->nodeValue); // relativize link
    $links[] = $link->nodeValue;
}

echo("<p>links</p>");
echo("<pre>");
print_r($links);
echo("</pre>");
```

gives the result:

```
Warning: main() [function.main]: unterminated entity reference vid=1&pid=1 in C:\Users\dir\public_html\whatisgoingon.php on line 14
links

Array
(
    [0] => /browse/product.do?cid=1
)
```

This line is causing the error and the truncation of the link. What is going on here?

```
$link->nodeValue = str_replace("http://www.test.com",'',$link->nodeValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&amp;` inside the URL must be being decoded when you reference `nodeValue`.  Wrap it in `htmlentities()`

```
foreach ($links_nodeList as $link) {
    $link->nodeValue = str_replace("http://www.test.com",'',htmlspecialchars($link->nodeValue)); // relativize link
    $links[] = htmlspecialchars($link->nodeValue, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /browse/product.do?cid=1&amp;vid=1&amp;pid=1
)
```

Comment: Don't use `htmlentities()`! `DOMNode` and friends output utf-8 strings. If you use bare `htmlentities()` on a string with non-ascii  characters you will get mangled output! You can use `htmlentities($link->nodeValue, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')`, but better to use `htmlspecialchars()` and output in 'utf-8'. Whatever you do, you *must* include the `'utf-8'` charset parameter!

Comment: If I change the `str_replace()` line to `$link->nodeValue = $link->nodeValue;` I get the same error, but if I change this line to  `$foo = $link->nodeValue;` and leave the next line as `$links[] = $link->nodeValue;` I get no error. So unless I am misunderstanding, it looks like $link->nodeValue gets decoded whenever it gets updated (rather than when it gets referenced). My prior question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897523/why-does-xpath-remove-html-special-characters) made me think this decoding was associated with the xpath operation but it seems I was wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @FrancisAvila Thanks for the clarification. I am curious why it is preferable to use htmlspecialchars() rather than htmlentities().

Comment: @jela `htmlentities()` will attempt to encode any and all entities it can recognize, which includes a number of UTF-8 characters. `htmlspecialchars()` encodes only characters used for special purposes in HTML/XML like `< > &`. I've edited it above.

Comment: `htmlentities()` changes too much. It will change every character that could possibly be a named html character reference into an character reference entity. Further, without an explicit charset, it will completely mangle your string. E.g. `htmlentities('é')` returns `&Atilde;&uml;`, which is `Ã¨`, i.e. *completely broken*. If you *do* use the charset parameter, then your string won't break, but you will have html that is unnecessarily longer and harder to process without a full-fledged parser and DTD.